# php script not executing on linux boot

Tags: php, linux, bash, google-chrome

I want some notifications whenever I boot my machine (Linux). So, I created a php script, it has some logic and I want to see the output of the script in the browser whenever I log in my machine.

I have added my php file in /etc/rc.local. but my browser doesn't open up after boot. May be its not able to find google-chrome's instance just after boot.

Any other suggestions, so that I can get popup just after log-in?

My php script ( tasks.php ):

```
$popUp = "Test task";
$popUp = "<html>$popUp</html>";
$fp = fopen("<path_to_file>/tasks.htm","w");
fwrite($fp,$popUp);
fclose($fp);
exec("google-chrome <path_to_file>/tasks.htm");
```

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

php <path_to_file>/tasks.php
```

Comment: try to give full path to to php interpreter /usr/bin/php <path_to_file>/tasks.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*google chrome* cannot be started during system initialization - first of all the windowing system is not ready, plus your account (that creates an X session) is not logged in yet.

You can however write a page, based on the execution of a PHP script (CLI in script)  in, for instance, /tmp

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/myaccount.tasks.htm","w");
```

then, when you log in, *google chrome* can be started automatically, having the file created as parameter. E.g.

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome /tmp/myaccount.tasks.htm
```

[This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) explains how to launch a program at login. (see the `~/.config/autostart` path if you are not using Ubuntu at the bottom of the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

rc.d scripts cannot interact with your X environment. You can execute your php script, but you cannot launch chrome.

You can move everything to the commands that start automatically when your X session starts (Gnome, KDE, etc...) and it will work.

Or, you can run the php script that does any job in the background via rc.d, and launch chrome via X session.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `gnome-session-properties`, it will run on login. (Obviously only if you use gnome)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my php script (tasks.php) which creates an html page.

```
$popUp = "Test task";
$popUp = "<html>$popUp</html>";
$fp = fopen("<path_to_file>/tasks.htm","w");
fwrite($fp,$popUp);
fclose($fp);
```

and added it to /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

php <path_to_file>/tasks.php
```

For opening my html page in chrome after log-in, I modified .config/autostart/google-chrome.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
# Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome <path_to_file>/tasks.htm
Name=Google Chrome
```